# Can't specify a dependency with a classifier in Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, groovy, dependencies

I've been searching for this for a day with no solution:

As per https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin,

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.12:grooid'
}
```

should declare the groovy grooid classified dependency and not the general one. However this doesn't work. The repositories have different structure, the above looks for:

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.6-grooid/groovy-2.5.6-grooid.jar
```

i.e. the classifier is appended to the version, while the repositories are:

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.6/groovy-2.5.6-grooid.jar
```

I've also tried the more verbose version:

```
compile (group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '2.5.6', classifier: 'grooid')
```

Which also doesn't work. Also read here, that gradle up to this day doesn't apparently support classifiers properly. So how do I remedy this situation?

Comment: In short, You have problem with implementation Groovy?

Comment: @deadfish Just the dependency, if I write it as compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.6' it compiles, but does not use grooid, instead it uses the default groovy Jars.

Comment: I've changed `minSdkVersion` to 26 and project builded with success

Comment: @deadfish not sure why, I'm at 26 and it doesn't resolve the depedency.

Comment: I'll publish project on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/SmithWhiteFirst/AndroidStudioGroovy

Comment: @deadfish nope, doesn't work. did you by any chance have the groovy jar in your libs folder? (1st dependency)

Comment: I've updated repo, moved grooid.jar to libs. Still works. Is that what You wanted?

Comment: What is your gradle version ? I did the test with the dependency and it did work : *https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.12/groovy-2.4.12-grooid.jar* is used

Comment: @ToYonos it's version 5.2.1